# C# атрибут XML повторяющий

Tags: c#, xml, парсер

прошу Вас помогите 3 дня уже почти сижу не могу понять как сделать. Есть ХМЛ документ вот пример:
Как видите, тут два атрибута <"ValType Type="> повторяются, мне нужен второй атрибут,      и прочесть все значение в нём, как и куда копать не знаю.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ValCurs Date="21.06.2019" Name="USD məzənnələri"">

    <ValType Type="Bank metalları">
        <Valute Code="XPD">
            <Nominal>1 t.u.</Nominal>
            <Name>Palladium</Name>
            <Value>2536.247</Value>
        </Valute>
    </ValType>

    <ValType Type="Xarici valyutalar">

                            <Valute Code="USD">
                    <Nominal>1</Nominal>
                    <Name>1 ABŞ dolları</Name>
                    <Value>1.7</Value>
                </Valute>


                            <Valute Code="EUR">
                    <Nominal>1</Nominal>
                    <Name>1 Avro</Name>
                    <Value>1.9202</Value>
                </Valute>


                            <Valute Code="AUD">
                    <Nominal>1</Nominal>
                    <Name>1 Avstraliya dolları</Name>
                    <Value>1.178</Value>
                </Valute>
            </ValType>
</ValCurs>
```

Comment: Это же только часть вашего xml, а вы просите парсить весь xml, который не показываете.

Comment: Извините, вот весь документ опубликовал

Comment: Покажите уже написанный вами код. Что-то же вы сделали за три дня?

Comment: За это время можно было хотя бы основы xml освоить. _тут два атрибута <ValType Type=>_ - нет, `ValType` - это элемент, `Type` - атрибут. Обратите внимание, даже тут на сайте, они выделены разным цветом.

Answer (score 2):

Используем LinqToXml.

```
using System.Xml.Linq;


var xml = XElement.Load(path);

var types = xml.Elements("ValType").Attributes("Type");

foreach (var type in types)
    Console.WriteLine(type.Value);
```

Вывод:

> Bank metalları
>   Xarici valyutalar

Comment: Alex спасибо Вам большое, скажите пожалуйста, каким способом теперь вывести на экран                             <Valute Code="USD">
                    <Nominal>1</Nominal>
                    <Name>1 ABŞ dolları</Name>
                    <Value>1.7</Value>
                </Valute> эти значение

Comment: @ДмитрийАгаев - не спрашивайте в комментариях. Пишите всё в вопросе. И покажите ваши попытки решения. И отформатируйте xml.